# Error:Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour: when plotting geom_line() and and setting ggplot(aes(colour=)) in 1 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a bar chart as in the code below: FC_TS is a data frame (36 x 3) consisting of 3 columns: Last Name, Feature (one of Action, Reflection, Flexibility_thinking, Structure), Value (1-7 for each of the Last Names, for each Feature (Screenshot FC_TS) and team_mean_diff (difference between the person's value and the team mean.

```
FC_TS: 

structure(list(`Last Name` = c("x", "y", "z", 
"u", "v", "t", "s", "g", "h", 
"x", "y", "z", "u", "v", "t", 
"s", "g", "h", "x", "y", 
"z", "u", "v", "t", "s", "g", 
"h", "x", "y", "z", "u", 
"v", "t", "s", "g", "h"), Feature = c("Action", 
"Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", "Action", 
"Action", "Reflection", "Reflection", "Reflection", "Reflection", 
"Reflection", "Reflection", "Reflection", "Reflection", "Reflection", 
"Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", 
"Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", 
"Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", "Flexibility_Thinking", 
"Structure", "Structure", "Structure", "Structure", "Structure", 
"Structure", "Structure", "Structure", "Structure"), Value = c(4, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 6, 6, 1, 
5, 6, 4, 7, 6, 1, 2, 2, 7, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2), team_mean_diff = c(0.111111111111111, 
-2.11111111111111, -2.33333333333333, -0.666666666666667, 0.111111111111111, 
2.88888888888889, -1.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
-0.111111111111111, 0.666666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 2.11111111111111, 
-0.111111111111111, -4.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, -0.888888888888889, 
-0.111111111111111, 1.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 2.11111111111111, 
-3.11111111111111, -0.333333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 0.111111111111111, 
2.88888888888889, 0.666666666666667, -1.66666666666667, -1.88888888888889, 
-2.11111111111111, 1.66666666666667, 0.333333333333333, -1.88888888888889, 
-0.111111111111111, -4.33333333333333, -0.666666666666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

TS_means is a data frame (4x2) with columns mean_name (Action, Reflection, Flexibility_thinking, Structure) and mean (mean value of last names per Feature). I_TS_means and S_TS_means are the industry mean for each of the 4 Features and the Stage means for each of the 4 Features, (4x2 as well). The three means are plotted as lines on the bar chart (Screenshot Plot mean lines).

```
TS_means:

structure(list(mean_name = c("Action", "Reflection", "Flexibility_Thinking", 
"Structure"), means = c(3.88888888888889, 4.11111111111111, 5.33333333333333, 
2.66666666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

[image: Plot mean lines]

```
TS_bar <-
  ggplot(FC_TS, aes(x = factor(Feature, level = level_order), y = Value)) + geom_col(aes(fill = `Last Name`), position = "dodge") + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 7)) + scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 7) + theme_bw() + geom_line(data = TS_means, aes(x = `mean_name`,y = `means`,group = 1,colour = "#28d7ac")) + geom_line(data = I_TS_means,aes(x = `mean_name`,y = `means`,group = 1,colour = "#2a2b63")) + geom_line(data = S_TS_means,aes(x = `mean_name`,y = `means`,group = 1,colour = "#f2eff2")) + scale_color_manual(values = c("#28d7ac", "#2a2b63", "#f2eff2"),name = "Means",labels = c("Team Mean", "Industry Mean", "Stage Mean")
) + ggtitle("Founder Check Evaluation: Thinking Style") +
  xlab("Thinking Style") + ylab("") + scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Action','Flexibility', 'Reflection','Structure'))
```

Now I want to include the functionality of highlighting the columns in "Structure" if they are higher than 5 in addition to the mean lines that I already plotted. So far, I only managed to highlight without plotting the mean lines at the same time (Screenshot highlight) since it gives me the following error if I do: *"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): colour".*
[image: Plot highlight]

```
TS_bar_1 <- ggplot(
             FC_TS, 
             aes(
               x = factor(FC_TS$Feature, level = level_order), 
               y = FC_TS$Value, 
               colour = (FC_TS$team_mean_diff >= 2 | FC_TS$team_mean_diff <= - 2))
             ) +
             scale_colour_manual(
               name = 'High Structure', 
               values = setNames(c('red', NA),c(T, F))
             ) + 
             geom_col(
               aes(fill = `Last Name`), 
               position = "dodge"
             ) + 
             coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 7)) + 
             scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 7) + 
             theme_bw() + 
             geom_line(
               data = TS_means, 
               aes(x = `mean_name`, y = `means`, group = 1)
             ) + 
             geom_line(
               data = I_TS_means, 
               aes(x = `mean_name`, y = `means`, group = 1)
             ) + 
             geom_line(
               data = S_TS_means, 
               aes( x = `mean_name`, y = `means`, group = 1)
             ) + 
             ggtitle("Founder Check Evaluation: Thinking Style") + 
             xlab("Thinking Style") + 
             ylab("") + 
             scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Action','Flexibility', 'Reflection','Structure'))
```

Is there a way to have the mean lines and highlighted bars in one plot at the same time?

Comment: Please share your data using ``dput(data)`` rather than screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: @user438383 of course, I just did!

Comment: What is `I_TS_means` and `S_TS_means` ?

Comment: @RonakShah they have the same structure as TS_means but other values